# How do I render multiple pages with BaseDocTemplate in ReportLab platypus?

Tags: python, pdf-generation, reportlab, platypus

I'm new to ReportLab and trying to generate a PDF with Platypus where each section has a different page template (and different header and footer). How do I do this with BaseDocTemplate without using SimpleDocTemplate?

I'm trying the code below but I can't get the contents of the frames to show, except for the first page where I'm drawing to the canvas directly. For the sake of brevity I've remove the extra formatting and the headers and footers code for each PageTemplate.

```
from reportlab.platypus import (BaseDocTemplate, Paragraph, Spacer,
                            PageBreak, Frame, PageTemplate, NextPageTemplate)
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib import pagesizes, units, styles, enums

class Report(object):
    def __init__(self, stream, sections):
        self.stream = stream
        self.sections = sections
        w, h = pagesizes.A4
        self._width = w
        self._height = h
        self._story = []
        self._doc = None
        self._canvas = canvas.Canvas(self.stream)
        self._stylesheet = styles.getSampleStyleSheet()

    def generate(self):
        '''Generate the report'''
        self._doc = BaseDocTemplate(self.stream,
                                    pagesize=(self._width, self._height),
                                    showBoundary=True
                                    )
        # Start with the coverpage, then create a new page for each section.
        self.coverpage()
        for i, p in enumerate(self.sections):
            self.render_section(i, p)
        self._doc.build(self._story)
        self._canvas.save()

    def coverpage(self):
        '''Draw the cover page'''
        frame = Frame(0, 0, self._width, self._height)
        self._doc.addPageTemplates(PageTemplate(id='cover', frames=[frame]))
        self._story.append(PageBreak())
        # The cover page just has some drawing on the canvas.
        self._canvas.saveState()
        self._canvas.setFont('Helvetica', 16)
        self._canvas.drawCentredString(self._width / 2.0, self._height - 108,
                                       "This is the first page")
        self._canvas.restoreState()

    def render_section(self, num, text):
        '''Put stuff on the canvas that belong to this section.'''
        frame = Frame(0, 0, self._width, self._height, showBoundary=1)
        self._doc.addPageTemplates(PageTemplate(id='section-%d' % num,
                                                frames=[frame]))
        h1 = self._stylesheet['Heading1']
        h1.alignment = enums.TA_CENTER
        frames = [NextPageTemplate('section-%d' % num),
                  Paragraph(self.sections[num], h1),
                  Spacer(1, units.inch * 0.2),
                  PageBreak()]
        self._story.extend(frames)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Report('report.pdf', "Why is this not showing?".split(" ")).generate()
```

Answer (score 7):

Your answer lies [here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/123612-basedoctemplate-with-2-pagetemplate/). The sample code on the given link is pretty clear on how to show multiple frames using BaseDocTemplate.

Comment: +1. I felt Reportlab docs didn't elaborate on how Frames interact with page templates and how page templates work with docs.